A loop that wraps a circle exactly once cannot be deformed to a point. Why?
I have very elementary ideas of paths and loops in a topological space. Let $X$ be a topological space and $I=[0,1]$ is unit interval on the real line. Then the map $$\alpha : I\to X,$$ is called a path with an initial point $x_0$ and final point $x_1$, if $\alpha(0)=x_0$ and $\alpha(1)=x_1$. We have a loop, if $\alpha(0)=\alpha(1)=x_0$ where $x_0$ is called the base point.
I am a physics student. Yet I am very eager to understand the following in terms of homotopy $F(s,t)$. Suppose my topological space is a circle i.e., $X=S^1$. All paths that do not completely wrap the circle once (say, covers the circle from $\theta=0$ to $\theta=2\pi-\delta$, where $2\pi>\delta>0$, and then back to $\theta=0$), can all be continuously deformed to a point. What is the homotopy $F(s,t)$ that achieves this?
On the other hand, if a closed path in this space wraps $S^1$ once, it cannot be continuously deformed to a point. Why such a homotopy $F(s,t)$ does not exist in this case?

Note that a path doesn't suddenly become non-nullhomotopic once it goes around the circle: you can still go back the way you came. What determines whether a path is nullhomotopic is its winding number, i.e. the net number of times it goes around the circle. For example, if $l$ is a loop around the circle (e.g. the identity $S^1 \to S^1$) and $\cdot$ denotes path composition, then $l \cdot l \cdot l^{-1} \cdot l^{-1}$ is nullhomotopic. This is quite clear if you imagine actually wrapping a string around a circular object and then pulling on it.

There is an important distinction to be made, namely between homotopy and path homotopy. A homotopy is intuitively a continuous deformation of one path into another. A path homotopy, on the other hand, has the additional property that it also preserves the end points, i.e., if $F(s,t)$ is a path homotopy between two paths $f$ and $g$, then $F(0,t)=f(0)=g(0)$, and $F(1,t)=f(1)=g(1)$, for all $t$. Notice that in this case $f$ and $g$ must have the same end points.
Now, in your example, in order to be able to provide a homotopy we need to know the parametrisation of your path $\alpha$. I will assume next that $\alpha=(cos(ks),sin(ks))$. You can take $k\leq 2\pi$ if you want your path not to cover the entire circle. With this, a homotopy that deforms your path to the point $(1,0)$ is
$$F(s,t)=(cos(ks(1-t)),sin(ks(1-t)).$$
In the case when $\alpha$ is a loop going around the circle once ($k=2\pi$) you can also take the same homotopy to deform $\alpha$ to a single point. However this is not a path homotopy since it does not keep the end points fixed. Indeed, one can see that there is no path homotopy between the loop $\alpha$ and any constant path on the circle.
